# Is the any math function that change the power of denominator of an input fraction?

Tags: functions, fractions

I'm seeking for a function that gets a fraction as input and change its denominator power in the log function like follow:

$f(\frac{a}{b}) = log(\frac{a}{b^k})$

Is it possible to find a function like f?

p.s: The input of function is not a and b, it's $\frac{a}{b}$ and I need the definition of function, like $f(r) = r^2$.

Comment: Such a function does not appear to be well-defined (as a function of a single variable).  The problem is that two different representations of the same fraction can result in different answers.  You could define it as a function of two variables, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function as follows.  Let $f(a/b) := \log(a/b^2)$ where $a$ and $b$ are [relatively prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) positive integers.  The function $f$ "maps" positive rational numbers (i.e. fractions) to real numbers.  Note that $f$ is not smooth or continuous.

Comment: When $a$ and $b$ are not relatively prime, you can divide them by their lcd prior to calculating $a/b^2$

Answer (score 0):

If the input is not $a$ and $b$ but a fraction $r$, you can use continued fractions to find the corresponding $a$ and $b$ such that $r = a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, and then apply your formula. But as stated by @irchans the obtained function is not continuous

Comment: When they are not relatively prime and we don't know the value of a and b, it's not possible to make them relatively prime by dividing them by their lcd.

Comment: @user137927 The continued fractions  algorithm provides a pair $(a, b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. If it is not the case, for example because you use another algorithm to get $a$ and $b$, we can then use the obtained values to calculate their lcd, and then obtain new values which are relatively prime

Answer (score -1):

Many functions (taking $a$ and $b$ as inputs) can be manufactured. How about $$f(a,b) = log(\frac{a}{b})+ \sum_{n=1}^{k-1}log(\frac{1}{b})$$

Comment: The input is not a and b, it's their fraction, and that's the problem.